# Range based for loop does not check all elements in vector of structs

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a tree for a file system, each node having a name, a size, a type (file or directory, and a parent node (supernode) and a child node (subnode), the node type is defined so in this struct:

```
struct Node {
    std::string name;
    std::string type;
    int size;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> subnodes;
    std::weak_ptr<Node> supernode;
};
```

And then initialised using this function:

```
auto add_node(std::string a_name, std::string a_type, int a_size, std::weak_ptr<Node> a_supernode) -> std::shared_ptr<Node> {
    
    Node temporary_node;
    
    temporary_node.name = a_name;
    temporary_node.type = a_type;
    temporary_node.size = a_size;
    temporary_node.supernode = a_supernode;

    return std::make_shared<Node> ( temporary_node );
}
```

I have a find() function to traverse the tree and find a specific node, once found, it returns the node:

```
auto find(const Node& node, std::string target) -> std::shared_ptr<Node> {
    auto identifier = std::make_shared<Node> (Node {});
    for (const auto& itr : node.subnodes) {
            if(itr -> name == target) {
                identifier = itr;
                break;
            } else {
                find(*itr, target);
            }
    }
    return identifier;
}
```

Then in main, I have a root node called 'tree' and then I create nodes to resemble a file system:

```
auto main() -> int {
    auto tree = std::make_shared<Node> ( Node { "/" });
    tree -> type = "root";

    auto current_node = tree;

    std::shared_ptr<Node> new_node = add_node("FOLDER_A", "directory", 0, current_node);
    current_node -> subnodes.push_back(new_node);

    std::shared_ptr<Node> new_node1 = add_node("FOLDER_B", "directory", 0, current_node);
    current_node -> subnodes.push_back(new_node1);

    current_node = find(*tree, "FOLDER_A");

    std::shared_ptr<Node> new_node2 = add_node("FOLDER_C", "directory", 0, current_node);
    current_node -> subnodes.push_back(new_node2);

    std::shared_ptr<Node> new_node3 = add_node("FOLDER_D", "directory", 0, current_node);
    current_node -> subnodes.push_back(new_node3);

    current_node = find(*tree, "FOLDER_D");

    return 0;
}
```

The nodes initialise just fine, but the problem is with the second time the find() function is called, where it will not iterate over all the subnodes, and skips straight to the return statement and returns an empty node. This is wierd, because the first find() call works just find and does change current_node to 'FOLDER_A'.

I would expect for the find() function to iterate over all the nodes, and find the node which is clearly there and return it, but for some reason the for loop does not go all the way the second time find() is called, and as a result the current_node is not changed to FOLDER_D. Is there perhaps an issue with my pointers here?

Edit:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
```

Comment: `find(*itr, target);` -> `return find(*itr, target);` probably the most common mistake with recursion is to not recurse

Comment: "with the second time the find() function is called, where it will not iterate over all the subnodes, and skips straight to the return statement and returns an empty node." is this really what happens? How do you know that this is what happens? did you actually use a debugger or are you just guessing?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I did use the debugger, I simply described what I saw. I also dont understand how your suggested modification would help.

Comment: I admit, I do not understand the code completely, but `find(*itr, target);` must be wrong. `find` does not modify its arguments, it returns something, but the return value is ignored.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This is the whole code, copy and pasted exactly as it was

Comment: actually not much is missing https://godbolt.org/z/oaTzdvYvj. Though your code produces no output, so its hard to tell what exactly you expect to happen. Its easier if you add some output and explain what you do get as output and what should the output be instead

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the second call of the find() fails to return a node.

Comment: includes are missing. Includes are part of the "whole code". Without includes the code does not compile. I dont understand why it has become so common to remove them, I mean the first thing I need to do when trying to understand the code is to add them back..

Comment: Why don't you try copy/pasting "the whole code" into a new empty file, nothing else, then see how many hundreds of error messages come out, when you try to compile it. But, yes, the recursive `find` call is obviously broken. That's the bug.

Comment: Sorry, here are the includes
```#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
```

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How is it broken? How would I go about fixing it?

Comment: You were already told how to fix it. See above. Did you read the very first comment at the top? Which part of it is unclear?

Comment: " the second call of the find() fails to return a node." no. It always returns a node. The problem is that when it is not among the first level of subnodes then your code ignores it and returns an empty node. Because of `find(*itr, target);` missing a `return`

Comment: Additionally, the best way to improve someone's chances of getting help on Stackoverflow with their problem, is to make it as easy as possible for everyone else to reproduce your problem, with minimal amount of work. Demanding that others stitch together the problematic code, from multiple chunks, including pulling the very first chunk from the comments, greatly reduces one's chances of getting helpful assistance.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number so if the code would not ignore it, it would return a node? Where should the missing return go in the function?

Comment: the function does return a node always. It cannot not return a node. `find(*itr, target);` calls a function that finds a node and the ignores the result of that function call. What do you want to do with the result of that function call?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number to update the current_node in main() to a different node

Comment: we are not in `main`. We are in `find` at the line `find(*itr, target);` What do you want to do with the result of this call?

Comment: `add_node` is a poor name for a function that does not add a node to anything.  Perhaps `create_nide`?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Discard it? Its useless if its not the node being searched for?

Comment: @Clifford yes that would be a better name

Comment: How do you know it's useless? How do you know that it didn't find the node, recursively? And if it's so useless, why even call it? Just remove it it doesn't do anything. And after removing it, does the rest of the remaining code make any sense at all, whatsoever?

Comment: discard? Now I am lost. Why do you call it then in the first place?

Comment: fwiw, you need not add "EDIT" to an edit. The edit history is visible here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74899950/revisions. You should place the includes on the top of the code where they belong. And for bonus points you can remove the text in between, because then it is simpler to copy/past the code in one click

Comment: My question has been answered by @molbdnilo , thank you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive functions work *exactly* like non-recursive functions.
In particular, local variables are local to a function *call*, and functions return to their immediate caller.

You never use the result from the recursion, so it's just discarded.

I would expect the function to return an empty `shared_ptr` on failure, and look something like this:

```
auto find(const Node& node, const std::string& target) -> std::shared_ptr<Node> {
    for (const auto& itr : node.subnodes) {
        if (itr->name == target) {
            return itr;
        } else {
            auto result = find(*itr, target);
            if (result)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: i find it a little strange that it recurses down all the way also when the target is the eg second subnode, but then on the other hand any traversal order is as good as any other

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether the goal is depth-first or breadth-first, but the attempt looks like depth-first.

Comment: @molbdnilo It was supposed to be depth-first

Answer (score 0):

Result of the recursive call to `find(*itr, target);` is not propagated up. Must set the return value with the result:

```
identifier = find(*itr, target);
if (identifier->name == target)
    break;
```

Comment: Partly true. Partly false. It's true that the return value is ignored. But, this exact change won't work.

Comment: @SamV how about now?

Comment: This looks as best as it could possibly look, given the lack of a [mre] in the question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Im confused, apart from the includes (which ive now given), this is the whole code, in the exact order it appears in my file? How could this example be improved?

Comment: It can be improved so that everyone can select a chunk of text just once, copy and paste it into a new empty file, and get your results. I challenge you to do just one copy paste, from this question, into a new empty file, then get identical results to your current code. It will be quite a nifty trick.